# Count value across multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files that contain the same type of data. I want to count the occurrences of a certain value in a column across all the csv files (they are too large to process as one file). It would be nice to have the result in one Series just as if you count occurrences of one file. How would I be able to achieve this with pandas?

An example would be this:

```
file 1

gender
-------
man
woman
woman
woman


file 2

gender
-------
man
man
woman
woman


Result

 man 3
 woman 5
```

Comment: Just read the csv and concat it , and value_counts

Comment: The files are too large to do that

Comment: Then you can chunk read , only keep the count result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can read each file individually in memory, you can use `collections.Counter` to build a list of counters.

Then aggregate them in a final step via `sum`.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

file1 = StringIO("""gender
man
woman
woman
woman""")

file2 = StringIO("""gender
man
man
woman
woman""")

# replace file1, file2 with 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv'
lst = [Counter(pd.read_csv(f)['gender']) for f in [file1, file2]]

# aggregate list of Counter objects
res = sum(lst, Counter())

print(res)

Counter({'man': 3, 'woman': 5})
```

If you cannot load even a single file into memory, you can use `csv.reader` with `collections.defaultdict` to iterate line by line and reach the equivalent result.

Comment: If I do this, the output shows the count of the last file only instead of counting them all.

Comment: @Stijn, That's not true. As my example shows, it aggregates across multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have a list `file_list` with the file paths that you want to read. Then you can loop over all files and store the occurrences of the entries in the column you are interested (say `gender`)

```
import pandas as pd

series_list = []
for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    count_series = df['gender'].value_counts()
    series_list.append(count_series)

total_counts = pd.Series()
for ser in series_list:
    total_counts = total_counts.add(ser, fill_value=0)

print(total_counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to perform chunking and aggregation silently.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('*.csv')  # use all csv files in directory

res = df['gender'].value_counts().compute()
```

This returns a series à la `pd.Series.value_counts`.

The `dask` solution, which utilizes `pandas` algorithms on chunks, will work even if a single file cannot be loaded in memory.